# Inequality on a pseudo convex domain

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

I'm on the exercise 8.14 page 63 of [https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~demailly/manuscripts/agbook.pdf](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7Edemailly/manuscripts/agbook.pdf) . Here is what I've tried : If $z$ is close enough to the border (on a neighbourhood  $V$ of this one in which $d$ is $C^{2}$), we can suppose $d \delta_{z} \neq 0$. Since $-log(\delta)$ is plurisubharmonic,
for all $\xi \in \mathbb{C}^{n}$ and $z \in V$
$$-\frac{H \delta_{z}(\xi)}{\delta(z)} + \frac{|d'\delta_{z}(\xi)|^{2}}{|\delta(z)|^{2}} = \frac{1}{\delta(z)}\sum_{1 \leq j,k \leq n}-\frac{\partial \delta}{\partial z_{j} \partial \bar{z}_{k}}\xi_{j}  \bar{\xi}_{k} + \frac{1}{\delta^{2}(z)}(\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{\partial \delta}{\partial z_{j}}(z)\xi_{j} )\bar{(\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{\partial \delta}{\partial z_{j}}(z)\xi_{j} )} \ge 0$$
Let be $\epsilon > 0$. It's enough to consider the case $\epsilon < 1$ and $|\xi| = 1$. Suppose the result is not true : there exists $0 < \epsilon < 1$ and $(z_{n})$ (which converge to  $z \in \partial \Omega$) and $(\xi_{n})$ (a sequence of vectors such that $||\xi_{n}|| = 1$)  such that
$$-\frac{H \delta_{z_{n}}(\xi_{n})}{\delta(z_{n})} + \epsilon \frac{|d'\delta_{z_{n}}(\xi_{n})|^{2}}{|\delta(z_{n})|^{2}} + n < 0.$$
It's seem to not be relevant.

However, as $\epsilon < 1$, it's enough to show that forall $t < 1$, $t \frac{|d'\delta_{z}(\xi)|^{2}}{|\delta(z)|^{2}} < C$ forall $||\xi|| = 1$ and $z$ in a certain neighbourhood of $\partial \Omega$. But I don't see why it could be true.

I wish you a good day.

Comment: I guess $H$ is the Levi form, but what is $\delta_z$ and the function $d$ ? Can you post a self-contained wording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it : one shows that $-H \delta_{z}(\xi) \ge  -C ||\xi |||d'\delta_{z}(\xi)| ~ (1)$ for $C > 0$ large enough. Then one writes $C = \frac{C}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}\sqrt{\epsilon}$, devides by $\delta(z)$ and use the inequality $xy \leq \frac{x^{2} +  y^{2}}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Halbaroth and thanks for your answer. First I correct a mistake : d doesn't exist here (I misunderstood with $\delta$). $d'\delta_{z}$ means I consider $\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{\partial \delta}{\partial z_{j}}$ valued in $z$ (i.e. $\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{\partial \delta}{\partial z_{j}}(z)$ ). It's the notations Demailly uses in his book.

And $H f_{z}.\xi$ means $\sum_{k; j }\frac{\partial^{2} \delta}{\partial z_{k} \partial \bar{z}_{j}}(z)\xi_{k} \bar{\xi}_{j}$ for all f $C^{2}$.

PS : I'm french, so sorry for the mistakes.